# ArrayList been overridden when calling a method inside a for loop and method does firebase calls

Tags: java, for-loop, google-cloud-firestore, callback

This method getBedHistory takes an input as list of beds called allBedsWithoutStatus() and a date. I have 34 beds in my allBedsWithoutStatus(). It calls a method called calculateStatus() and then calculates the status, and passes it back as an integer. The results used to create a new array allBedsWithStatus().  The new array allBedsWithStatus only contains the details of my input array (allBedsWithoutStatus)

Status =  open = 0; allocated = 1; etc…

calculateStatus includes a firebase call which has an oncomplete listener which makes it an asynchronous method so I therefore added the callbackb which is intended to wait until the method completes before it returns with the status.

The calculateStatus method is rolling through the bedIds and getting the status at the date correctly.

However, on runtime this routine drops straight to bottom of method and returns 0 for every status

when I return to the calling method getBedHistory() (see below) The last element in my arraylist is showing 34 times and status of 0 for that bedId

```
public void getBedHistory() {
        int statusCode = 0;
        for (int u = 0; u < allBedsWithoutStatus.size(); u++) {
            bedIdString = allBedsWithoutStatus.get(u).getBedId();
            wardIdString = allBedsWithoutStatus.get(u).getWard();
            System.out.println("Before calculate This the bed id and ward id " + u + "  " + bedIdString + " " + wardIdString);


                 bedStatusAtDate  =  calculateStatus(bedIdString, new Callbackb() {
                @Override
                public void callb() {


                    System.out.println("This is the bed status at date  = " + BedStatusChartsForDate.this.bedStatusAtDate);

                    // Put as much as the logic we can here
                    // all i need is the status of each bed
                    switch (wardIdString) {
                        case "St Johns":
                            wardCode = 0;
                            break;
                        case "St Marys":
                            wardCode = 1;
                            break;
                        case "St Pauls":
                            wardCode = 2;
                            break;
                        case "St Magz":
                            wardCode = 3;
                            break;
                        case "St Joes":
                            wardCode = 4;
                            break;
                        default:
                            wardCode = 5;
                    }  // end Switch for Ward

                    bedStatus[0] = statusCode;
                    bedStatus[1] = wardCode;
                    bedDetails.setBedId(bedIdString);
                    bedDetails.setWard(wardId);
                    bedDetails.setStatus(statusCode);
                    BedStatusChartsForDate.this.allBedsWithStatus.add(bedDetails);
                    int size =  allBedsWithStatus.size() - 1;
                    System.out.println("List of all beds with status added end of getBedHistory = " + "  " + size + " " + allBedsWithStatus.get(size).getBedId() + allBedsWithStatus.get(size).getWard() + " " + allBedsWithStatus.get(size).getStatus());

                }
            });
        }
```

```
// Method here to get all the beds from the beds collection to then to be passed in to get the bed history in the next method
public int calculateStatus(String bedId, Callbackb callbackb) {
    System.out.println("This the bed Id before using db call "+ bedId);
    //   System.out.println("this should be details returned "+   .getAllBedDetails());
    //Now get the history of the bed to get the status
    db.collection("bed")
            .document(bedId)
            .collection("bedHistory4")
            .orderBy("dateAndTime")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task1) {
                    if (task1.isSuccessful()) {
                        String event = "";
                        String eventDateString = "";
                        Date eventDateFromDb = new Date();
                        Date dateSelectedFromScreen = new Date();
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot history : task1.getResult()) {
                            eventDateString = history.getString("dateAndTime");
                            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                            SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                            try {
                                eventDateFromDb = format.parse(eventDateString);
                                dateSelectedFromScreen = dateFormatter.parse(dateFromDateSelected);
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            //   System.out.println("This is date time returned " + ": " + eventDateFromDb);
                            //   System.out.println("This is date time string  " + ": " + dateSelectedFromScreen);

                            //Storing the eventType for transactions before or equal to the selectedDate
                            if (eventDateFromDb.compareTo(dateSelectedFromScreen) <= 0) {
                                event = history.getString("eventType");
                            }
                        }
                        // end For loop
                        // now use the event to set the status in the bedStatus array.
                        switch (event) {
                            case "Added bed":
                            case "Bed allocated to ward":
                            case "Bed is now open":
                            case "Bed is cleaned – ready for next patient":
                                statusCode = 0;
                                break;
                            case "Bed allocated - patient on way":
                                statusCode = 1;
                                break;
                            case "Patient in bed in ward":
                                statusCode = 2;
                                break;
                            case "Bed ready for cleaning":
                                statusCode = 3;
                                break;
                            default:
                                statusCode = 4;
                                System.out.println("This bed is the bed not created yet" + bedId);
                                break;
                        }   // end Switch for bedStatus

                        System.out.println("Bed details added to all beds with status " + bedId +  " " + " " + statusCode);
                        callbackb.callb();
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task1.getException());
                    }

                }
            });
    return statusCode;
```

Comment: You are returning statusCode from calculateStatus before the oncomplete method has been called. But your code is incomplete: you don't show where statusCode, bedStatus or bedDetails are declared.

Comment: @tgdavies
Thanks for your reponse
 int statusCode;
 ArrayList<BedInfo> allBedsWithStatus = new ArrayList<BedInfo>();
    int[] bedStatus = new int[]{0, 0};
    BedInfo bedDetails =  new BedInfo();
All these are global 
You are correct it Is returning before it executes the onCompleteListener.
I put in the callback to try and delay the return until the oncomplete was completed.
That does not appear to be working any suggestions?